# Why do I need to use backslash or escape character in order to access a sql file i.e. "/home/algolix/Downloads/poolstore_co_uk_primary\ .sql"

Tags: command-line, mysql, database

I'm trying to import mysql database using:

```
mysql -u root -p poolstore < /home/algolix/Downloads/poolstore_co_uk_primary.sql
```

but I can't and it says:

> No such file or directory

however, when I access it using:

```
mysql -u root -p poolstore < /home/algolix/Downloads/poolstore_co_uk_primary\ .sql
```

it works.

**So why do I need to use backslash?**

Answer (score 1):

`\` is called an escape character for a reason.

Your question is self explanatory ... your filename has a white space in it:

```
poolstore_co_uk_primary .sql
```

to write/read from such files you need to either escape the white space(*multiple white spaces need multiple escape characters one for each)* as you did:

```
poolstore_co_uk_primary\ .sql
```

or quote the filename like so:

```
'poolstore_co_uk_primary .sql'
```

Because, providing the file name in the command line as it is without using either method above will be split(at white space) by the shell into tow filenames:

```
poolstore_co_uk_primary
```

and

```
.sql
```

and removing the white space(as you did in your first command) will result in a totally different third filename.

Answer (score 1):

Your filename contains a blank character before the dot which needs to be escaped with a backslash because otherwise it would start a new argument.

Your first command tries to open file `poolstore_co_uk_primary.sql`.

Your second command accesses the file `poolstore_co_uk_primary .sql`.

Obviously those are two different files. Apparently the second one exists on your system while the first one doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

One of several things your shell (for example, bash) does before a command is even called is to segment your input. This is typically done on the basis of whitespace characters. For example,

```
ls projects personal shared
```

would be segmented into four parts: `ls`, `projects`, `personal` and `shared`. The first part is typically interpreted as the command you want to call, the remaining are parameters. So, the commandline above would call `ls` with three parameters.

If one of the parameters contains a whitespace character, this segmentation goes wrong. Let's say you want to list the contents of the directory called "new projects". The commandline

```
ls new projects
```

would be segmented into `ls`, `new` and `projects`. The shell has no way of knowing that you actually meant `ls` and `new projects`.

As the other answers already mentioned, there are ways to signify that a whitespace character isn't meant as a separator between parts of your input. One way is to mask the whitespace character with a backslash

```
ls new\ projects
```

Another way is to quote the whole segment

```
ls "new projects"
ls 'new projects'
```

It looks like the file name of the database dump you want to import contains a whitespace character. So (to use a simplified example),

```
mysql < poolstore .sql
```

would be interpreted as `mysql`, `<`, `poolstore` and `.sql`. But you need `mysql`, `<` and `poolstore .sql`. So you need to "tell" your shell not to segment on that specific whitespace character.